# Devices with iOS 15 ignore my sandbox account during test in-app purchases

Tags: ios, testing, app-store-connect, testflight

We have recently updated several test devices from iOS 14.7.1 to 15.2. After that, when trying to make a test purchase inside our app, TestFlight ignores the sandbox accounts (which we add to Settings -> Apps-Store -> Sandbox account) and uses the main account that is used for purchases in the App Store.

The SandBox account works fine if you log out as the main user in the App Store - but then you can't use TestFlight to download test builds.

maybe someone has faced a similar problem and knows the solution or will tell me in which direction to look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> TestFlight ignores the sandbox accounts (which we add to Settings -> Apps-Store -> Sandbox account) and uses the main account

That is correct behavior. The sandbox account is for when you are running an Xcode build. TestFlight, on the other hand, always uses your real account, but it doesn't charge you (and the same for your beta testers).

Comment: Apparently, you're right.
But before ios 15, it worked exactly as I described - applications from TestFlight used sandbox accounts.
I can be sure of this because now I am holding a test device iPhone 12 mini (ios 14.7.1) and when trying to make a purchase in our application (installed via TestFlight) - a SandBox account is used.
My sandbox accounts have the format:
**name@gmail.com**
And the account for the App Store and TestFlight has the format:
**name@company.com**
![SandBox Account when making a purchase](https://ibb.co/tsRwnrp).

Apparently, it didn't work quite right before

Answer (score 1):

@matt is right. The only what I can add here is that after you
logged in as sandbox user > attached device to xcode > run the build > made the purchase with sandbox user
you will be able to use that sandbox user even in next TestFlight builds.

For other testers this new approach is very uncomfortable, expecially if tester has a very complex password for their primary accounts... Apple made these things worst, for sure.

Btw, important to note that making purchases using primary account in sandbox environment (liek your testers do in TestFlight builds) will also reset the subscriptions in some time range. Not sure what exactly, probably from 5min to 1h. I didn't know it and had tons of questions, why my app doesn't recognise any previous subscription made recently. Purchase restore response also says that there is nothing to restore... Weird way of tasting, Apple...